# Yii2 Autocomplete

Tags: yii2, autocompletar

tengo un formulario y quisiera el autocomplete que busque en todos los campos de la tabla con un solo input o entrada, en _search lo hace como hago para seleccionar el compo y rellene el formulario o tienen un autocomplete mas optimo gracias.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'descrproducto')
          ->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'desPro']) ?>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: de paso échale un ojo al select2 de kartik para yii2

Comment: el motivo con  kartik para yii2, solo me retorna el valor de la descripcion, tambien necesito el id, ejemplo
1, profesional
2, obrero
y asignarle un id, para q haga la busqueda con JS, y retorne los datos de otras
tablas relacionadas.

Gracias